# Cypress test ran with browser vs head-lessly

Tags: cypress

How can I debug a test that is failing when ran headlessly but passing
when ran with a opened browser ?

below is the error I'm getting when running the test without opened browser:

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'Logout' within the element: [ <a.navbar-item>, 2 more... ] but never did.
```

Meaning ... the test passes locally but fails within CI tool.
Please ask if you need to know any details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest recording a video and using console.log statements in your test. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos.html#Screenshots

Comment: Yes, I know about this. I know I can take screenshots and recordings but that isn't helping. That only shows how it passes within the browser it won't show you why it fails when executed **programmatically**. In other words the executing test "sees" the html element when rendered and it won't "see" it when ran **programmatically** not being rendered.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by this. Are you saying that it passes when you record a video running headless mode, but when you don't record a video it fails? headless mode is always using a browser and rendering a DOM.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. By headless I mean the test runs in the terminal without browser being opened.

Comment: When you run it headless are you using the same browser as when you run it in the GUI?

Comment: Yes I do. I'm using default Electron.

Comment: I've got an update. I just noticed that it fails only within CI tool. So it passes locally headlessly and non-headlessly but it fails when running in the CI. It must be CI specific issue. I'll reach out to people at Cypress.

Comment: Would you please take a look at the screenshot I attached ? It appears that the test is failing when trying to fetch data from the backend. I'm still dealing with it.